# Equivalent forms Optimization

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming

We were told to assume in class that the below optimization formulations are equivalent-

$$\min_w\max_{\delta:||\delta||_F\leq\epsilon}||(X+\delta)w-y||_2^2$$

$$\min_{w}||Xw-y||_2^2+\lambda||w||_2^2 $$

for appropriately chosen $\lambda$.

$X,\delta\in R^{m\times n},~w\in R^{n\times1},~y\in R^{m\times1}$

Can someone please explain why this is true? A reference paper pointing this out would also be appreciated.

Comment: What does $\|\delta\|_2$ mean when $\delta$ is a matrix?

Comment: $\text{L}_2$ norm for matrices is the Frobenius Norm

Comment: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v28/yang13e.pdf

Comment: There's a perfectly standard defenition of the 2-norm of a matrix that isn't the Frobenius norm.  Wny not write $\| \delta \|_{F}$, since that's what you mean?

Comment: The lasso is the $\ell_{1}$  norm

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.09169.pdf

Comment: I've edited the question to remove $\|\delta\|_2$. It really was just wrong as written. @angryavian, when $\delta$ is a matrix, $\|\delta\|_2$ refers to the induced $2$-norm, which coincides with the maximum singular value.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Thanks, I am familiar with both definitions. I was just trying to get OP to clarify, since I have seen some people use $\|\cdot\|_2$ to refer to Frobenius norm, while [most] others use it to refer to operator norm.

Comment: Fair enough. I consider the Frobenius interpretation incorrect. Let’s fight the good fight!

Comment: As written above, see [Lecture Notes on Ridge Regression](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.09169).